# "-bash: expo: command not found" after installing expo-cli

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I've just installed expo-cli with `npm install -g expo-cli`, but if I try and run an expo command, I just get the error `-bash: expo: command not found`. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling expo-cli, and changing my .profile and .bash_profile to add the path to the global node_modules directory, but I just can't get expo commands working. Any idea why?

Comment: What operation system do you use and what is the path that you've currently added? Also, at this path, can you see the expo-cli directory?

Answer (score 2):

For any `expo` command, try running:

`$ npx expo <your command(s) here>`

Using the command above solved the
`-bash: expo: command not found` error for me.

(`$` denotes the terminal prompt)

I also ran `npm install -g expo-cli` *before* running my command above.

Answer (score 0):

1st I enabled the finder to show hidden files by writing following commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE 
killall Finder
```

Then I searched for the expo files under my user:

```
macintoch HD>Users>MyUserName>
```

I found the expo file under the following folder:

```
~/Users/MyUserName/.npm-globalHomebrew/bin
```

Then I added the folder in the Path by executing the following commands:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-globalHomebrew/bin
```

I checked if it is added successfully by typing the following command:

```
 echo $PATH
```

Run then the following commands to login to expo:

```
 expo login
 expo whoami
```

Comment: Also it is not necessary to enable hidden files in macOS by terminal command. There is a hotkey to toggle macOS hidden files visibility: ```Cmd+Shift+.```